# Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android', version: '1.6.21', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I started learning Kotlin in Android studio a few days ago and I still haven't figured it all out, so having this problem is a big question mark for me, I know nothing yet about gradle. [Screen of faild gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odJQN.png)

I just created a new empty activity and it suddenly appears out of nowhere.

this is my buildgradle file :

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir}
```

Answer (score 11):

I was able to fix this by disabling offline mode of gradle and syncing.

Access the below by going to View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle

[If button is off, press it twice to disable offline mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ml1eN.png)

Comment: I was skeptical, but this actually worked for me!

Answer (score 5):

This problem occurs when there is and older version of the package (org.jetbrains.kotlin.android) so the error denotes for updating the package version .

add the following line to your **PROJECT LEVEL GRADLE FILE** INTO THE PLUGLINS

```
plugins {
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false }
```

NOTE : USE THIS VERSION "1.7.20" INSTEAD OF "1.6.21"

Answer (score 1):

Android studio will install org.jetbrains.kotlin.android automatically. When you click "sync with Gradle Files" first time, Android studio didn`t react to it. After your second click, it did. that`s all.

I solve this problem by changing my vpn,which make Android studio can connect to google.

below for someone like me in China:
我的解决办法是，Android Studio设置里开代理（socks）,这个时候你点“sync with Gradle Files”，会有弹窗，记得**勾选HTTPS代理**，然后就行了，等它下好就行。
（其实，不要手贱点掉HTTPS代理就不会有问题QAQ）

不勾选HTTPS代理的话，在v2rayN那里会显示rejected。

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32023852)

Answer (score 1):

be care full wire 1.7.20 I was getting errors because I was writing 1.7.2 missing 0 at the end

```
plugins{
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt" version "1.7.20"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is now solved .... for some reason. I just want to add that I really don't understand why (in case someone wants to help me haha).

I tried to open another project, in another widow and I did exactly the same thing. I created a new empty activity to see if the problem was with my computer or the internet. But it wasn't. Everything worked perfectly well. No gradle problems. So I closed the second project, with the idea of really trying to find an answer for my main project, but suddenly it just... worked. I did NOTHING. I just opened a second project.

I really don't get it.

Comment: I solved it by connecting to the internet and hitting 'Try again'. It downloaded the package.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me. I just created a new project and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a the latest version, the current latest version is:

```
plugins{
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt" version "1.7.20"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your plugins to

```
plugins {
   ...
   id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.0' apply false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your top-level (Project) build.gradle, add this line:

```
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
```

So, it will look like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There's one more reason for this problem.. In my case the VPN was blocking the Android studio for internet access. I turned off VPN and tried opening it ... It worked.